# Can you exclude URLS from the Spring x509 support?

Tags: spring, x509, authentication

We are currently using Spring x509 support for client-auth. The app server is JBoss in which the verify-client="want" has been set.

However what I observe is once I add the x509 element to the spring configuration file, it will try to load a digital certificate for every http request. However I dont want it to do that for the login page. Unless the user clicks on a specific button (say 'Login with Certificate') on the login page, I dont want the certificate to be loaded and used.

Is there a way to exclude any particular URLs? Or once you have an x509 element in the  element for Spring configuration, it will try to load the certificate for every http request?

Here is part of my spring configuation:

```
<security:http create-session="always"> 
    <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern= ..... // not relevant to this question
            <intercept-url pattern= ..... // not relevant to this question
    <security:form-login
            login-page="myLoginPage" 
            authentication-failure-url="/myErrorPage" 
            default-target-url="/mySuccessPage"
            always-use-default-target="true"/>

</security:http>
```

Also if not in Spring, is there a way to specify an exclude URL on JBOSS:

Here is the  element configured in the JBOSS standalone.xml

```
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="alias" certificate-key-file="keystore" verify-client="want" ca-certificate-file="truststore"/>
        </connector>
```

Comment: See https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html where is explains the _verify-client_ option (the part about "CLIENT-CERT authentication. See the SSL HowTo")

Comment: Also see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16350802/822870