# JBOSS 7 with two contexts. One with SSL Mutual Auth and the other just SSL

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, jboss, jaas

We are having a problem to configure our JBoss. We are tring to configure it to make it possible to use at the same time Mutual auth and to don't use it.
Like:

https://example.com/contextA/ (Requires SSL Mutual auth)
https://example.com/contextB/ (Just SSL)

Is it possible?

What I could do is to make or all the JBoss use SSL mutual auth or don't. How can I configure it to be both at the same time?

My contextA web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>ContextA</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>services</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name />
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

My contextA jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>RequireCertificateDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

ContextB web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>ContextB</display-name>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecureApplicationConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ContextB</web-resource-name>
            <description>Auth applications are secured</description>
            <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Only Users with roles are allowed</description>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecureChannelConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Entire site is protected through SSL</web-resource-name>
            <description />
            <url-pattern>/contextB/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>Require encrypted channel</description>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ContextBPolicy</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

ContextB jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/ContextBPolicy</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Content of standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="ContextBPolicy">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.ContextBLoginModule" flag="required"/>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>

(...)

<security-domain name="RequireCertificateDomain">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="CertificateRoles" flag="required">
            <module-option name="securityDomain" value="RequireCertificateDomain"/>
            <module-option name="verifier" value="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.AnyCertVerifier"/>
            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="file:c:/tmp/my-users.properties"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:c:/tmp/my-roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <jsse keystore-password="changethis" keystore-url="file:c:/tmp/localhost.jks" truststore-password="changethis" truststore-url="file:c:/tmp/cacerts.jks"/>
</security-domain>

(...)

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <configuration>
        <jsp-configuration x-powered-by="false"/>
    </configuration>
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
        <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="localhost" password="changethis" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/localhost.jks" verify-client="require" ca-certificate-file="../standalone/configuration/cacerts.jks" truststore-type="JKS"/>
    </connector>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's impossible to do this based on the http endpoint.

Reason being that the SSL/TLS-handshake happens BEFORE the client sends its http request to the server.

The endpoint (eg `/contextA`) resides in that http request!

At the start of the SSL/TLS-handshake, only the hostname  (eg `example.com`) is available (and only if the client has SNI enabled).

So you'll need 2 different hostnames for this. For example `contexta.example.com` and `contextb.example.com`

Comment: This is wrong. It can be done. The trick is to announce _verify-client=false_, accept the connection, then check the URL path and if it is _/contextA/ (Requires SSL Mutual auth)_ then restart the SSL handshake, this time having _verify-client=true_. Not sure how to do it with JBoss, but in general this is possible and is used in practice. I'll to post an example server later.

Comment: Hi David, what TLS message does the server send to the client to 'restart' its session? I can't find anything in the TLS protocol that talks about restarting a TLS handshake.

Comment: Not sure, but I think newer JBoss versions support such distinctions in the web.xml config (or if not there in the JBoss specific config file). Where the security things are configured. I'll try to find and post details if no one does it before me... (don't the ideas in other answers work?)

Comment: I was just interested in how such TLS handshake restart worked, just out curiosity (unrelated to the original question)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, since you want to configure different type of authentication for different WebApplications.

Please fix the value of `verify-client` to `want`:

```
<connector name="https" ...>
    <ssl .. verify-client="want" .../>
</connector>
```

**Added**

According to JBoss documentation related to the `verify-client` attribute:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html

*Set to `"true"` if you want the SSL stack to require a valid certificate chain from the client before accepting a connection. Set to `"want"` if you want the SSL stack to request a client Certificate, but not fail if one isn't presented.*

It is correct that if `verify-client=”true”` JBoss requires certificate. But if you access a certificate when `verify-client="want"` JBOSS should require a client certificate. If a brother contains a client certificate and an application is protected by the client certificate authentication (CLIENT-CERT in web.xml) it should success.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but i tried this, and no fixed the problem. JBoss only requires User Certificate when i set verify-client to true.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining a realm that requires a cert:

```
<security-realm name="CertRequiredRealm">
    <authentication>
        <truststore path="mytruststore.jks" password="mytruststorepassword"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

Then put your WebApplication in that realm:

in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>CertRequiredRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```